# Simulate calibrated camera in gazebo garden

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I have a calibrated camera, with calibration parameters specified in a yaml file. Is there a way to simulate this camera in gazebo (version = garden)?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Please [edit] and update your question.